# How to post data to Firestore as Timestamp data type - swift

Tags: swift, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I wonder how can I post data as `String` to `Firestore` as `Timestamp`. I am creating a sample app which store data on `tableView` and data are going to sort base on `Timestamp`.

So, in programming I have tried to get current time and date as `String` but I don't know how to set data to `Firestore` as field is `Timestamp`. When i query data from `Firestore` i want to sort data base on `Timestamp`.

```
let currentDateTime = Date()

// initialize the date formatter and set the style
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .long
formatter.dateStyle = .long

// get the date time String from the date object
formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)
```

`Timestamp` in `Firestore` contain date and time.
How can I post data as `String` to `Firestore` as `Timestamp`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to store a file under a time stamp or date in Firestore?

You seem to be doing a Time stamp literally as a date, a much simpler way would be storing it as a Time stamp this way as it will just be a number that will be ordered in Firestore.

```
   let timestamp = Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate*1000).description
```

[Image Link : This will be the end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlu2o.png)

Comment: I want to post data to Firestore with current date and time. Firestore already provide data type as `Timestamp` which include date and time `September 17, 2018 at 8:28:29 PM GMT+7`.  so, in programming i want to post data to Firestore with that `Timestamp` data type.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to post it as `String`? Here's my approach with an `Int` instead

`let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) // gives you an Int  like 1534840591`

Then when you parse it from `Firebase`, pass it to a `func` like something like this to convert that `Int` timestamp into a date:

```
 func timestampIntToString(integerTime: Int, timestampLabel: UILabel) {
    let timestampDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(integerTime))
    let now = Date()
    let components = Set<Calendar.Component>([.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .weekOfMonth])
    let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: timestampDate, to: now)
    var timeText = ""

    if difference.second! <= 0 {
        timeText = "now"
    }
    if difference.second! > 0 && difference.minute! == 0 {
        timeText =  "\(difference.second!) sec ago"
    }
    if difference.minute! > 0 && difference.hour! == 0 {
        timeText =  "\(difference.minute!) min"
    }
    if difference.hour! > 0 && difference.day! == 0 {
        timeText =  "\(difference.hour!)h"
    }
    if difference.day! > 0 && difference.weekOfMonth! == 0 {
        timeText =  (difference.day == 1) ? "\(difference.day!)day" : "\(difference.day!) days ago"
    }
    if difference.weekOfMonth! > 0 {
        timeText =  (difference.weekOfMonth == 1) ? "\(difference.weekOfMonth!) w" : "\(difference.weekOfMonth!)w"
    }

    timestampLabel.text = timeText
}
```

Comment: I post as String because when i get current time and date then the result will be like this `September 17, 2018 at 8:28:29 PM GMT+7`. Then i want to store it in `Firestore` and later on, when i query it then i can sort it base on the current date and time. For example, recent call it store data on tableView base on current date and time. I want to achieve something like that.